# How to set style for virtualkeyboard from android settings in qt qml

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

I connected the virtualkeyboard module and built android application (Qt 6.2), but for some reason the keyboard style is different from the one specified in the settings of the phone
[image]

In all others apps keyboard style is
[image]

[image: Code]

Comment: it can be better to share the code snippet to see how you got this output

Comment: I added a screenshot